# подсветка пункта меню при ховер popup меню

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, popup

Есть сайдбар, с popup меню. Не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы при ховере popup срабатывала подсветка пункта меню на сайдбаре. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать. Заранее, спасибо.

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu > a:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 10px;
 border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
 right: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu:hover > a:after{
 opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_sub_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 55px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/*Добавлено*/

.main_menu_content_list a:hover .main_menu_content_list_int {
  color: #FFE74C;
}

.main_menu_content_list a:hover .main_menu_content_list_tv {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="haveSubmenu"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int">1111</div>11111
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">11111</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">22222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">33333</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="haveSubmenu"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv">1111</div>22222
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">222211111</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">22222222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">222233333</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте правило в свой CSS:

```
.main_menu li:hover > a:not(:hover) {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Comment: почти подходит. Дело в том, что правило ховеров в моем меню выглядит так: .main_menu_content_list a:hover .main_menu_content_list_int {
  background: url('../images/hover/ico-inet-y.png'); 
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

Comment: т.е. для каждого пункта меню свое правило, т.к. у каждого пункта меню есть картинка, и соответственно, при ховере загружается своя картинка

Comment: добавил изменение. необходимо, что бы параметры значений main_menu_content_list_int и main_menu_content_list_tv менялись

Comment: Все, разобрался. Ваш ответ помог мне. Спасибо )